# trigonometry limits when $x$ approaches zero

Tags: trigonometry

a.) $\lim_{x\to 0} x/\sin x = 1$

b.) $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x/ x = 1$

Is a.) and b.) true?

Because if I try to apply this to $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin 17x/ x$, my answer is $17$, not $1$...

Comment: Both a) and b) are true.

Comment: But when I tried it with sin17x/ x I got 17.

Comment: This may seem counterintuitive in some sense, but the answer is actually $17$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Product of a number and an infinitesimal is still an infinitesimal*. So $17\times 0 \to 0$. Actually an infinitesimal means a value approaching to zero. So if you multiply something (ofc not infinity) with an infinitesimal  then you will get again an infinitesimal.

Next notice that $\frac {\sin {17x}}{x} =17\frac{\sin {17x}}{17x}$

Thus $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin 17x/ x=\lim_{x \to 0} 17\frac{\sin {17x}}{17x}=17$

Comment: Yes. That is what I did. Then 17x in numerator and denominator are cancelled out. 17(sin(1)) gives me some weird answer

Comment: Do you know why this does not equal to 1 if the above laws are true?...

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Comment: @user498021 You can't cancel the $17x$ from within the $\sin$ to get $\sin(1)$.

Comment: If I follow your reasoning then $\frac{\sin {\pi/2}}{\pi/2}$ must be equal to 1  but is it?

Comment: No... but they're said to be true?... I don't get it... And when I simplify my equation from earlier, how does 17(sin(0)) = 17?

Comment: Read my first line *product of a number and an infinitesimal is still an infinitesimal*

Comment: Yeah, so then how does one come up with 17 if it's product with 0 is 0

Comment: Infinitesimal does not mean zero, it means near to zero but greater than it.

Comment: Ok. But i'm still confused... when sin17x/17x becomes sin(0), then multiply the 17, which is 0 become 17?

Comment: You wrote yourself in the answer that it's product is 17, when the first statement says it should be infitesimal meaning 0;0000001

Comment: @user498021 "when sin17x/17x becomes sin(0)" Why should that be the case?

Comment: sin(17x) = sin(17(0)) = sin(0)?

Comment: yes but if you do that you get the undeterminate form $\frac 0 0$

Comment: I'm so lost...how is the answer 17

Comment: Wait... You don't put zero in place of x without doing certain manipulations. And that certain manipulations is $\frac{sinx}{x}=1$

Comment: did you read my answer?

Comment: Sorry. i'm a dumbass. I just put it all together and I see why it's 17 now. My bad for wasting your time

Comment: Using infinitesimal and limits in the same context is confusing.

Comment: @user498021 You didn't waste our time. You learnt something and made progress(not matter how slow) and that's important.

Comment: "Using infinitesimal and limits in the same context is confusing"-  you're totally right

Answer (score 0):

a) and b) are both true

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 17x} x=17\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 17x} {17x}$
Lets operate the changee of variable $y=17x$

$y\to 0$ as $x\to 0$

$17\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 17x} {17x}=17\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y} {y}=17\times1=17$

Comment: yes, I undertsnad now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can expand the taylor series of $\sin x$ this is very easy to see
$$\sin x = \frac{x}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}...\\
\implies \frac{\sin x }{x}=1-\frac{x^4}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}...\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x }{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}...\right)=1$$
Using this you can see that taking the inverse of this would work as well.

So 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin 17x }{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(17-\frac{(17x)^2}{3!}+\frac{(17x)^4}{5!}...\right)=17$$

Comment: Noooo, he is struggling with basic concepts of limits (not that it is a bad thing) and you are giving a circular answer with taylor series. How's it of any  help ?

Comment: I see that now. Let's leave this here so he knows why $lim \sin x/x$ is equal to 1

Comment: Isn't this circular reasoning ? How do you taylor series of $\sin$ without know $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x/x = 1$ in the first place ?

Comment: You don't need the limit to derive the taylor series. Taylor is a more advanced concept but this isn't circular reasoning.

Comment: This is circular reasoning. To derive the Taylor series of $f(x)=\sin(x)$ centered at $x=0$, you must use: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
Which requires the computation of $f'(0)$ to derive the first *non-zero* term. Now, how can one evaluate $\sin'(0)$? Fundamentally, we must use the definition of the derivative. Hence, this is the same as computing:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}-\sin{0}}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$$
Hence, you must know what $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is to know the Taylor series of $\sin{x}$ you mentioned above.